# How to make mqtt connection to adafruit from nodemcu via office proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, mqtt, esp8266

How to make mqtt connection to adafruit from nodemcu via **office proxy?**

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is not HTTP, it can not use a HTTP proxy.

MQTT over Websockets can be used with a HTTP proxy but it appears that the nodemcu MQTT client does not support MQTT over Websockets https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1584